# ubuntu 16.04 with i7 8550U can't shut down

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

My computer is ASUS X560UD i7 8550U. And I want to run dual system on it for deviding 500G for win10, and 500G for ubuntu 16.04. But when I install ubuntu, I found it can't be shut down. I has tried shutdown on terminal ,UI ways, and lots of ways whatever I can search. So I am wondering is that Ubuntu16.04 supports i7 8550U or not ? Are there any one else has the same problem as me ? Thanks a lot.

[This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HXP4yw6VtS/) is what I got after using "*sudo journalctl -b | pastebinit*"

Comment: I installed 18.04 today.But the problem still exists.

Comment: It is the NVDIA VGA problem. After installing the newest driver on the official website, the problem solved.